# How do I integrate pylint in online ace-editor

Tags: python, integration, ace-editor

I have a code for ace-editor where I am calling the ace.js script from the cdnjs
but even if the mode is set to  "setMode('ace/mode/python');", it is not catching the syntax errors linting/syntax errors like pycharm. Please help

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: are you looking for a way to run pylint in the browser, or on the server, ace doesn't have builtin support for any of this?